# Creating a Snapshot of a Database in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, error-handling, snapshot

On my instance I have a database called SampleDB. I want to create snapshot on it called SampleSnap.

```
-- Create a Snapshot on a Database
CREATE DATABASE SampleSnap ON  
( 
    NAME = SampleDB,  -- Logical File Name
    FILENAME ='C:\Users\Eleonora\Desktop\SampleSnap.ss' 
)  
AS SNAPSHOT OF SampleDB;  
GO
```

This gives me an error

> Directory lookup for the file "C:\Users\Eleonora\Desktop\SampleSnap.ss" failed error 5(Access is denied.).

What can I do to fix this?

Besides I can't understand the use of logical file name. What is it and how to specify it correctly?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a snapshot you must be member of the role **sysadmin**

Where **source_database_name** is the source database, **logical_file_name** is the logical name used in SQL Server when referencing the file, **os_file_name** is the path and file name used by the operating system when you create the file

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/create-a-database-snapshot-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

**Edit** - If it is not the sysadmin rights. Then its because the SQL Server Service Account doesnt have access to your path.

**Edit2** If you want it on C drive - I created a new folder C:\Test

I gave the NETWORK SERVICE Full control - Dont know if that is nessecary

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response @TomTom. It shows the same error when I try to save on any other path on C drive, not only Desktop, and I am a member of sysadmin role and the administrator of the OS. I am just studying on localhost, and C drive isn't on different computer.

Answer (score 1):

> What can I do to fix this?

YOu start with reading the error.

> Directory lookup for the file "C:\Users\Eleonora\Desktop\SampleSnap.ss" failed error 
>   5(Access is denied.).

is an operating system error telling you that the database server can basically not access the folder. SImple like that.

You COULD change permissions, or you just put the data not in your C users folder. Which is way smarter - db database files have no business on your DESKTOP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It shows the same error when I try to save on any other path on C drive, not only Desktop, and I am a member of sysadmin role and the administrator of the OS. Can you point out how to change permission? Thanks.